# Storing return type of Class<?>[]

Tags: java, generics

How do I store the results of a variable call if it returns `Class<?>[]`? This is generics at work I assume but I can't figure out how to store it.

for example when i do

myObject. -> here i get the list of methods in eclipse, when i go to the method i want it `returns Class<?>[]`

Comment: Could you give a code example?

Comment: Class<?>[] result = someMethod();. Did I miss something?

Comment: Ok - just seems odd to store it as an array of unknown type :/

Comment: Why is it odd to store something that you don't know the type of as an unknown type? If you knew the type, you could obviously store it as that.

Comment: @Ricki: it's not an array of an unknown type. It's an array of Class instances. It's just that you don'w know which type the Class represents. But all its methods (getFields, etc.) are still callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the questions shows a misconception with generics.
When a method returns

```
Class<?>[]
```

that's because you made it so it can return an array of any type of class.

When you actually use the method, it doesn't evaluate what the real Classes are, it just returns what was declared in the method signature. You can then check for each object you have in your result, and get the actual class. Generics is only a way to make weakly typed general classes (i.e. collections) a bit more strongly typed, it's not a processing mechanism. It will never find out what the `?` is for you.

If you know in advance what the `?` might be, change your method signature to indicate it. You can even declare it as something like

```
Class<? extends BaseClass>[]
```

to indicate that you expect only subclasses of BaseClass.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to remain generic you can store it in a

```
Class<?>[]
```

variable.

If you know the type and you don't need to remain generic, you can define a more restricted type variable and cast the result of the method at that type.